# Execute php files without .php extension

Tags: php

Hi am running an apache2 webserver - Ubuntu 18.04

The Thing is any of the php page would not run without the .php extension

my htaccess file.

> shorturl.at/yGPX6

My 000default file

> shorturl.at/gnqDO

Comment: Neither of your shortened links work, please update them. I would recommend using https://hastebin.com or https://pastebin.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Comment: Sorry but I'd prefer using web.config file